# Searching string in mysql table which similar sentences

Tags: php, mysql

How can I search text which similar sentences like that:

```
$search_input = "php beginner tutorial";

$sql = "select into mytable where 
            '$search_input' is ..something.. with `title_col`";
```

So, my results should be like this:

```
PHP: A simple tutorial - Manual
PHP 101: PHP For the Absolute Beginner | Zend Developer ...
Beginners PHP Tutorials- Home and Learn
PHP 5 Tutorial - W3Schools
Beginner PHP Tutorial - 1 - Introduction to PHP - YouTube
PHP Tutorial for Beginners - Webmonkey
PHP Tutorial- Tutorials Point
```

I though sometimes I might use split a string.

```
$search_input = "php beginner tutorial";
$search_input = explode(" ", $search_input);
$sql = "select into mytable where ";
for($i=0; $i<count($search_input); $i++){
    $sql .= "`title_col` like '%$search_input[$i]%' ";
    if($i != count($search_input)-1) $sql .= "or ";
}
//echo $sql; will be like below   
//select into mytable where `title_col` like '%php%' or `title_col` like '%beginner%' or `title_col` like '%tutorial%' 
//would you suggest me how to `order by` too?
```

but my column `title_col` is `utf8_general_ci` and some languages don't have a spaces between the sentences. How could I do this?

Comment: To MySQL `tutorial` and `manual`, or `PHP` and `Zend` are totally two different terms and to achieve the goal set above, you should have more than one table - `terms`, 'synonyms' and `terms_and_synonyms` tables. It can be done with two tables as well, but this way it's simpler.